# Organizing Div's, css box model

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So I'm putting a few boxes in my footer and right off the bat when I use margins to move them around they are moving the whole footer around as well. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The site: http://cowgirlsbaking.com/

---php---

```
<?php wp_footer() ?>
<div id="pinkpoint">
</div>
<div id="footnav">

<div id="footernavlinks>
</div>




</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---The css for the two divs---

```
#footernavlinks {
    clear: both;
    margin:10px 0 0 25px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image:url('http://cowgirlsbaking.com/wp-content/themes/autumn-leaves/images/footblockback.png');


}

#footnav {
    background-color: #EB7CDB;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen self, you run into this problem all the time and you should probably figure out the clean way to do it someday but you have a lot on your plate right now what with the cats being sick and your girlfriend hanging off your arm all the time when your trying to work and the sinking feeling that you might not be able to pay those medical bills anytime soon so just use this sloppy work around and get on with your life. Tonight I will put beer in you and everything will be ok.

```
#footnav {
    background-color: #EB7CDB;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0 0 0;
}

#footernavlinks {
    clear: both;
    margin:50px 0 0 25px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    background-image:url('http://cowgirlsbaking.com/wp-content/themes/autumn-leaves/images/footblockback.png');

}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I knew I could count on you. Now where are those miller light tall boys....

Answer (score 1):

You should close the quotation marks in your footernavlinks div:

```
<div id="footernavlinks">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **margin-top of 10px** on `#footernavlinks` is moving away `#pinkpoint` from the footer. You can see it with Firebug when hovering `#footernavlinks`
You could remove this margin-top or use a padding-top of 10px on the same element if you want to move it downwards without moving the whole footer.

What is the actual content of this footer? (text, links, images)

Comment: The box that I am trying to move around is a repeating image embedded in the css. If I add padding to it it just makes the box bigger, I just want to move it without pushing #pinkpoint or the rest of the footer around.